# How to handle with the encoding/decoding in HTML ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have the following issue. When i try to open folder through IE, the address bar can not resolve the characters which are non-latin letters, for example if the text contains "ø" the adress bar will resolve it like "Ã¸".
I use the following code in C#:

```
projectLink.NavigateUrl = "file:///" + filePath;
```

I tried also in some different meta charset in html, probably all type of encodings, i will upload picture to get better vision! 
Thank you!!!

Comment: is it a file path or a url?

Comment: Will a IE open the file. If the IE cannot open the file then you are using an invalid character in the URL.

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx help? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I use the following code projectLink.NavigateUrl = "file:///" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(projectName) , if i try to open it in Chrome, there is no problem, bet when i try it through IE the adress bar translate the characters in some other symbols

Comment: Please update your post with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your usage of:

```
projectLink.NavigateUrl = "file:///" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(projectName)
```

to:

```
projectLink.NavigateUrl = "file://" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(projectName)
```

or:

```
projectLink.NavigateUrl = "file:///" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(projectName)
```